# Preg_match a string, must containing Letters and numbers

Tags: php, string, preg-match

The sentence maybe:
BenQ G2420HDBL 23.6" Wide LCD Monitor

Need to grab the "G2420HDBL" part. The letters and numbers may be in a different order but still remains a string with both letters and numbers present.

Comment: which is the final string you are looking for?

Comment: @yes123, quotting AndrewC: "*Need to grab the "G2420HDBL" part*"

Comment: Define what the actual rules are. Is 'BenQ? always the start. Do you need to get the piece between the spaces? You want the piece starting at the 6th position? ... There are hundreds of conditions one can think of, and you may get dozens of answers that won't help you.

Comment: @andrew: this model number you wanted to grap does contain any spaces between?

Comment: @yes123 No spaces, however it could contain a hyphen "-".
That string could be at any position within the sentance. Also no specific words that it will follow.
Basically match the first string that contains both numbers and letters in any order.

Comment: So you're basically trying to extract the model number from an arbitrary product description string. Will it always be in the same position in the string (ie right after the manufacturer name)? Are you sure all model numbers are in a format that just contains letters and digits? How about hyphens? Slashes? Spaces? I've seen all those in model numbers. And what if the string also contains other alpha-numeric bits?

Comment: What about brand names containing numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex in case-insensitive mode:

```
(?=[a-z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-z])[a-z0-9-]+
```

Basically it matches the *first string that is made up of only letters and numbers with atleast one letter and atleast one number*.

In PHP:

```
if(preg_match("/(?=[a-z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-z])([a-z0-9-]+)/i",$input,$match)) {
   echo $match[1];
}
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/z0vDc)

Comment: @yes123: Just add the `-` to the character class. You don't have to give negative votes for such things. Its a trivial extension of what I've already given. Anyways I've edited my answer.

Comment: @codaddict: actually I gave `-1` because I think there are much easier regex for doing it. This is a mostruosity imo

Comment: @yes123 This will `/(?=[a-z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-z])([a-z0-9-]+)/i`

Comment: @codaddict It might be, but its the first solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = substr($name, 6, strlen($name) - 28);
```

Comment: if the input is `$string="BenQ G2420HDBL 23.6";` then the output is `2420HDBL 23.6`

Comment: Childish? There wasn't any more information at the time of writing. My other answer contains a more specific construction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ctype_alnum`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) but there is probably a better way using regexes:

```
$str = "BenQ G2420HDBL 23.6";
$pieces = split(' ', $str);
$theStr = '';
foreach($pieces as $piece) {
    if(ctype_alnum($piece)) {
        $theStr = $piece;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Karim79 your solution did not work. Upon further investigation I found out by using the ctype functions together a workable solution could be found.

I believe these PHP built in functions are faster then a regex formula.

WORKS: 
`$str = "BenQ G2420HDBL 23.6";
    $pieces = split(' ', $str);
    $theStr = '';
    foreach($pieces as $piece) {
        if(!ctype_alpha($piece) && !ctype_digit($piece) && ctype_alnum($piece)) {
            $theStr = $piece;
            break;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what you actually need. This regex finds strings containing any numbers, letters and dashes. Only the string cannot start or end with a dash.

```
$name = 'BenQ -1G2-420H-DBL- 23.6" Wide LCD Monitor';
$a = preg_match('/\b(([0-9A-Z]+[A-Z0-9]+)[-]*)+\b/i', $name, $m);

var_dump($m[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this, just had to str_replace the dashes. @codaddict The regex formula was just a split second slower than this one.

```
$str = "BenQ G2420HDBL 23.6";
$pieces = split(' ', $str);
$theStr = '';
foreach($pieces as $piece) {
    if(!ctype_alpha($piece) && !ctype_digit($piece) && ctype_alnum($piece)) {
        $theStr = $piece;
        break;
    }
}
```